# Trouble with Java Enumerations, Methods, and Classes

Tags: java

I have to write a program for class, to learn classes, fields, methods, and enumerations. 
I am for the most part lost, the class felt rushed through learning these things, and was only given a couple of examples in class, unrelated, no homework. I believe I have the constructors in, and maybe have the String `toString` bit right. The full directions and my code so far are below. If at all possible, I would rather not just be given the complete answer, I want to try to work through it and learn from it.

My specific questions for now are:

1. How do I incorporate the `addTopping` bit below into the code?
2. Where does it go, and what parts need changed?
3. I have prices for everything, where do I put those in?

Some start of starting point would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, and I use public for everything because while private was mentioned in class, was never really told if there was a specific protocol of which to use when.

Directions for it are:

> For your next assignment, you are to create a class to represent pizzas, and then write a main program to exercise your class. A pizza has the following properties:
>
> - A size: small, medium, or large.
> - A number of toppings (from 0 to 3) from the following list: pepperoni, sausage, meatball,green peppers, onion, black olives, and mushrooms.
> - A price.
>
> You will need a field for the size of the pizza and a field for each possible topping (so four additional fields). The price should not be stored in a field, but rather, calculated, using the values of the other fields. The pizza class will need an additional field to store the number of toppings on the pizza.
>
> Your pizza class should have the following methods:
>
> - void addTopping(Topping topping) // Adds a topping. This is an error if the pizza already has four toppings.
> - int getPrice() // calculates and returns the price of the pizza and toppings.
> - String toString() // Returns a string describing the pizza.
>
> In addition, the class should have constructors to make a zero-topping pizza, a one-topping pizza, a two-topping pizza, and a three-topping pizza (four constructors in all).
>   In addition to the class, you should write a test program (you can use the main method of the pizza class for this) to test all of your methods.
>   Also, the program should use enumerations in a meaningful way.

My code so far is:

```
enum Size {SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE};

public class Pizza {  
  public String size;
  public String topping1;
  public String topping2;
  public String topping3;


  public String toString() {
    return (size + " " + topping1 + " " + topping2 + " " + topping3);
}

  public Pizza(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
    size = a;
    topping1 = b;
    topping2 = c;
    topping3 = d;
}

  public Pizza(String a, String b, String c) {
    this (a, b, c, null);
}

  public Pizza(String a, String b) {
    this (a, b, null);
}
  public Pizza(String a) {
    this (a, null);
}


  public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
}
```

Comment: _I have to write a program for class_ ... then do. If you need help, come back with a specific problem

Comment: Please don't bury your question - make it easy for people to figure out what it is you're asking.

Comment: Some friendly advice, assuming this is for a college class: If you feel lost, take advantage of your professor's or TA's office hours or any other resources your department provides. Helping you get your head around this stuff is their job :) You'll have better luck here with more specific questions, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have already tried asking the professor, a couple of times. While he is quite intelligent, getting things explained doesn't work nearly so well. I asked him, and several other classmates, to find they are also lost. Only came here because I am trying for any option I can. I was warned against this site, for any and all questions, that most are rude. I see now I was wrong to come here at all. Thank you Ben, and the user below, for courtesy, and what help you did offer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you were to make an enum for the 3 possible toppings and then treat them as an enum instead of as a string. this way to "iilegal" values can be given to your constructors (for example "asdasd" as a topping which you clearly don't want to get).

you should search up enum and read about it if you have no idea when I'm talking about but in general the very basic syntax is:

```
enum E {
    A, B, C
}
```

then I can use it as a type (just like int, String etc). for example:

```
public void foo(E e) {
    //do something
}
```

and this function will only get a variable of type E as a parameter, which can be either A, B or C which we have defined.

you got the methods you need to implement interface (that means - their name, parameters, and return value type). use these as your code structure and implement the code according to it.

And on a side node, making class data members public is very bad practice is most cases. Allways make them private unless you are 100% sure of what you're doing. Making then privates prevent unwanted and unmonitored changes to your instance variables

Answer (score 0):

> How do I incorporate the addTopping bit below into the code? Where
>   does it go, and what parts need changed?

It should go into the Pizza class. This is not the site for more detailed hand-holding, I'm afraid.